# Updating Location on Google Maps - API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently working on a small project and can't get my head around an issue I'm facing with the updating the location on a Google Map via the API.

Quick run down (This part is all working)
- Have a MySQL database with some lat and long values
- On the click of a buttonI use Ajax to hit a PHP script which pulls a random lat and long from the database and encodes to json.
- I successfully retrieve the lat and long values and can alert them or insert them anywhere on the page.

Here is where my problem is. I am using a Google Maps API snippet which works perfectly fine. It shows the map and, if I hard code a lat and long value in a function that fired at the click of a button, it re-centres the map to the new location. However, when I insert the lat and long values via the Ajax script, it doesn't update the location.

Here is my code (Only the front end jQuery. The PHP and ajax controllers work.)

```
<script>
var map;
function initialize()
{
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954,12.556663),//Setting Initial     Position
zoom: 2
});
}


function newLocation(newLat,newLng)
{
map.setCenter({
    lat : newLat,
    lng : newLng
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function ()
{
$("#1").on('click', function ()
{

// Get lat and long new values from MySQL
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'core/ajax_controller.php?c=controller',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    newLocation(data[0],data[1]);
    map.setZoom(15);

}

});

});
});
</script>
```

From the example above. If I alert or print data[0], for example, which holds the lat value, it displays a value as plain text - "26.1725364". However, when adding it to the map function "newLocation" it doesn't seem to pass through to the function, and recenter the map.

However, If I remove the Ajax and just have the following, with hard coded lat and long coordinates. It works, each click of the button updates the map centre.

```
$("#1").on('click', function ()
{
    newLocation(12.12345678,12.12345678);
    map.setZoom(15);
```

So, it appears my problem is somehow accessing a second javascript function "newLocation" within another function.

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: This is only a fast guess... But try: `newLocation(data[0].lat,data[0].lng);` in the success callback. Or `newLocation(data.lat,data.lng);`

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette, no joy though. The issues doesn't appear to be relating to the function grabbing the data. As I said, if I move   newLocation(12.12345678,12.12345678); outside of the ajax request, it works using the hardcoded values. So the error must have something to do with calling that function inside of the current function maybe.

Comment: In the callback, please add : `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` and post the result. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - ["-33.847973","150.6517684"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` result from the Ajax request is an array of strings.

So a quick fix would be:

```
success: function(data) {

    newLocation(parseFloat(data[0]),parseFloat(data[1]));
    map.setZoom(15);

}
```

Comment: That was the fix! Thanks for the help.
So, I didn't realise that the function reads it different to what it would from just alerting it or inserting it on the page as plain text.

Comment: You also could make your server to send `data` formed in json like `{lat:-33.847973,lng:150.6517684}` and pass it straight to your function like this: `newLocation(data)`. But it's code efficiency talks. ;) I often say, if it's not broken, don't fix it! lol

Comment: Consider accepting the answer and maybe an upvote!! ;)

Comment: Of course.
That's another way of doing it, possibly an iteration for me to make as I progress.